# Server provisioning and deploy of a RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm currently working on providing server provisioning and deployment automation of certain project. I have decided to use Sprinkle & Capistrano. I'm actually stuck dealing with ssh user stuff since i want, as part of provisioning phase with sprinkle, to create a "deploy" user which should be used by Capistrano to perform deployment. The problem I'm facing is related to the way i should configure deploy.rb, i don't know how to setup user & password (let's say "root") to be used by sprinkle and after that change them to the new created "deploy" user to perform deployment with Capistrano. Provisioning and deployment are two different phases but they share the same configuration, maybe there are some tricks to do that; anybody out there with experience in this area?

Comment: Will the deploy user's username change from server to server, or can you use the same username?

Comment: Deployer's user name and password does not changes from server to server. The same happens with root credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure Capistrano's deploy user like so:

```
set :user, "deploy_username"
```

You can also set the password using `set :password, "secret_password"`, but it's probably more advisable to either enter the password manually, or have sprinkle set up SSH keys for you.  This will avoid having the password stored in plaintext.

Sprinkle has similar settings under the `ssh` block:

```
ssh do
  user 'sprinkle_user' # defaults to 'root'
  password 'secret'
end
```

but the same issues apply here - you should probably supply the password manually for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using ElasticBox to provision your Rails server in any cloud.

You just need to create a custom box for the purpose or use the Rails box to automate it.

The box abstraction provides you the flexibility to add any customization steps to your files (like the deploy.rb), and you can also add the scripts for doing any ssh configuration to the server in deployment time.

Here is a good blog post that explains **How to Deploy a Multi-Server Rails App using ElasticBox:**
https://elasticbox.com/blog/deploy-multi-server-rails-app/